# How to export data from google appengine in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to export data from data store of appengine to .CSV format. But I cant find anything in java which will be useful to export it. Do I need to setup python and then only I can do it. But I dont want in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple choices to export your data and you will have to investigate each one to see which one fits the bill.

- Assuming that you are using Java, write a Servlet that can take the request, query your datastore and create the data to be exported. The Servlet can then return back the correct MIME Type to allow the downloading of the file.
- You can use the URL Service to push data out of your system. This will assume that the Service that you invoke resides somewhere else.

Please ensure that if you go with a Servlet that does the work, then look at Securing that endpoint - so that only authorized users can do that.

Here is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992534/writing-to-a-pdf-from-inside-a-gae-app/14994879#14994879) that shows how you can export a PDF file from your application. While the example is that of PDF, you can easily customize the Template for your CSV file. The MIME type will be text/plain.

Comment: yes I wrote a servlet in th GAE app where I have defined a query and then executed it. In that servlet am executing query but am getting empty result. Is it neccessary to deploy this app on GAE again and then run this servlet on appengine.

Comment: Or we can excute this servlet in the hosted mode also.

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you have tried and why the results are not coming. But here are some points: 1) You can execute your servlet in both local dev mode and hosted mode. By hosted mode, I understand you mean deploying to GAE. So technically, both approaches should work and you should get results. 2) There are chances that your queries may not be returning at results if the correct indexes are not setup. 3) Turn your logging to a more detailed level and observe the Log via the Administration Console. If there are problems running in GAE, it would show up there.